# Convert mm:ss to Milliseconds in PHP

Tags: php, time

Can you please let me know how to convert mm:ss to milliseconds in PHP.

`$value = "10:10"`

`$ms = ...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to do string conversions or array manipulations:

```
sscanf($value, "%d:%d", $minutes, $seconds);
$ms = $seconds * 1000 + $minutes * 60 * 1000;
```

Answer (score 3):

`$ms = intval(substr($value, 0, 2))*60*1000 + intval(substr($value, 2, 2))*1000;`

Comment: @Aung: Cooper's answer is better as it doesn't depend on the number of digits.

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = "10:10";
$time = explode(':',$value);
$ms = $time[0]*60000 + $time[1]*1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = "10:10";

list($minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $value);

$milliseconds = $seconds * 1000 + $minutes * 60000;

var_dump($milliseconds); // 610000
```